# assigning a picture's length to a button's length

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a picture:

```
<div class="poster">
  <img src="someSource.png">
</div>

<style scoped>
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.poster{
  width: 260px;
  height: 146.25px;
}
</style>
```

This picture's length is set to `260px` as you can see but when screen gets smaller its size also gets smaller which is expected and ideal.

I also have this button below the picture:

```
<div class="play-button">
  <button class="base-button btn" >HELLO
  </button>
</div>

<style scoped>
.base-button{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.play-button{
 width: 246.17px;
 height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

This button's length doesn't change when screen gets smaller like my picture do. How can I make my button to get smaller like my picture? They both should have exactly the same length all the time. I can also use `.scss` in my project but can't figure out a way to make both elements have the exact same length!

Comment: Please try sharing your code inside a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This was difficult for me when I first started working with CSS, so I know your struggle here.

To make the button the same width as the image, I would wrap the two elements within the same div. So, my HTML would look like this:

```
// The class 'wrapper' can be any name you would like.
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="poster">
    <img src="someSource.png">
  </div>
  <div class="play-button">
    <button class="base-button btn" >HELLO</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For your CSS, I recommend setting the width of the wrapper div to fit-content, and change the width of the button to 100%. Here is the CSS, which only has two lines edited!!!

```
.wrapper {
/* This could also be a specific width. However, you would need to change
 '.poster' to width: 100% for it to be the same length as the button */
  width: fit-content;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.poster{
  width: 260px;
  height: 146.25px;
}

.base-button{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* Changing the width to 100% will make the button equal length with the image. */
.play-button{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
}
```

[Here's a live demo if you want to see how it works.](https://codepen.io/jambalaya04/pen/PoWEBMG)

Answer (score 0):

One option is below:

```js
// here we iterate over the 'div.poster' elements using NodeList.prototype.forEach:
document.querySelectorAll('div.poster').forEach(
  // an anonymous Arrow function; 'poster' is a reference to the current
  // div.poster element-node of the NodeList over which we're iterating:
  (poster) => {
    // here we set the inline style of each poster element to be
    // equal to the naturalWidth of the <img> contained within (if
    // you're programatically including images, or all images are -
    // or should be - the same width, this won't need JavaScript, 
    // but for a more dynamic approach this seemed relevant:
    poster.style.minWidth = `${poster.querySelector('img').naturalWidth}px`;
  });
```

```css
/* a simple 'reset', to ensure all elements are sized similarly,
   share the same font-size, line-height, margin and padding: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.poster {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  /* using flex layout: */
  display: flex;
  /* orienting the flow vertically, so
     the <button> is below the <img>: */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* providing some spacing between adjacent
     items: */
  gap: 0.2em 0;
  margin: 1em;
  /* hiding the overflowing content that
     exceed the border-radius: */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- wrapping the <img> and <button> elements inside of
     a div.poster element: -->
<div class="poster">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/500/300">
  <button>Play</button>
</div>

<div class="poster">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/400/400">
  <button>Play</button>
</div>

<div class="poster">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/500">
  <button>Play</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c71xqu6w/).

As above, the same demo, but with all `.poster` elements' `min-width` set to `260px`:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.poster {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.2em 0;
  margin: 1em;
  min-width: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="poster">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/500/300">
  <button>Play</button>
</div>

<div class="poster">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/400/400">
  <button>Play</button>
</div>

<div class="poster">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/500">
  <button>Play</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c71xqu6w/1/).

These flex-posters can, of course, be coupled with a `display: grid` ancestor to form a grid of poster-images; for example:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(260px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
}

.poster {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: flex;
  /* here we use column-reverse to ensure that the <button> is always
     visible in the 'poster' element, as otherwise - with a specified
     row-height, and a picture with a large y-height - it could often
     be pushed out of the visible area. With column-reverse instead
     the <img> is cropped by the upper boundary of the 'poster' instead: */
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  /* spacing the <button> and <img> apart where possible, positioning
     each at the flex-start or flex-end position: */
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1em;
  min-width: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="poster">
    <!-- note that the <button> now precedes the <img> element in the DOM, this
         is because I used "flex-direction: column-reverse" to ensure that the
         <button> was always present at the bottom of each "poster" element: -->
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/870/790" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/580/630" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/550/770" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/590/270" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/420/510" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/650/360" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/800/600" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/720/910" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/760/460" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/710/570" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/660/490" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/580/790" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/260/810" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/650/640" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/620/350" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/510/660" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/830/240" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/870/850" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/590/820" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
  <div class="poster">
    <button>play</button>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/420" alt="An image of Bill Murray, taken from the 'www.fillmurray.com' website, used to represent a typical poster-image.">
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c71xqu6w/3/).

References:

- [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width).
- [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).